# WebExtensions -- Blocking an HTTP request until event trigger

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm building an extension where the basic concept is this:

1. Intercept HTTP Request matching a URL pattern (we'll call it example.com/match)
2. When HTTP Request is intercepted, block it and insert some HTML into the page
3. Wait until a click event on that inserted HTML THEN "release" the HTTP request.

I"ve got 1 and 2 down, and it uses a background script and a content script. The trick is that the function that can block a http request must also return it, at which point the request is released. The docs are here:

Here's my implementation in background.js:

```
browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    processResponse, 
    { urls: ["https://example.com/match/*"] }, 
    ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
);

async function processResponse(details){
    //Send a message to the tab's content script to inject HTML
    browser.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, {"insertHTML": true});

    await ???

    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
}
```

I'm fairly sure this needs to be done with an async function, as inclued above. However, await expects a Promise to be resolved to continue, and there's no way that I can pass a promise into that function in the background script from the content script for the particular inserted HTML.

Any ideas? This has stumped me for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a promise that only resolves when it receives a message from the background script.